# Анимация полета самолёта с одновременным изменением его размера

Tags: html, css, svg, анимация, css-animation

На одном из сайтов видел анимацию полёта самолёта с одновременным увеличением, уменьшением размера самолёта во время полёта вдоль трассы движения.

Ниже картинки, показывающие изменения размера самолёта в зависимости от место положения на трассе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как реализовать анимацию изменения размеров самолёта во время анимации движения вдоль трассы полёта?

Answer (score 4):

Выбираем карту с нанесенными городами
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбираем Юникод иконки самолета `&#9992;` ✈

- Так как это по сути текстовый элемент, то можно его стилизовать как
  текст, подбирая размер, цвет, координаты.
- Для анимации движения самолёта вдоль трассы  используется [animateMotion](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion)
- Для анимации изменения размеров самолёта используется
  [animateTransform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateTransform) c `type="scale"`

```
<!-- Анимация полета самолетов вдоль маршрута  -->
  <text  fill="dodgerblue" y="3.5" x="-5" font-size="10px"  >  &#9992; 
    <animateMotion id="AnM" dur="8s" begin="svg1.click" fill="freeze" rotate="auto"   >
    <mpath xlink:href="#Moskwa" />
    </animateMotion>
          <!-- Анимация увеличения, уменьшения размера самолёта -->
    <animateTransform  attributeName="transform" type="scale" keyTimes="0;0.2;0.8;1" values="1.5;4;4;2.5" dur="8s" begin="svg1.click" fill="freeze" />
</text>
```

Для всех остальных самолётов фрагмент кода, показанного выше повторяется.

Различия лишь в  `<mpath xlink:href="#Moskwa" />` трасс полёта

Ниже полный код.

***Анимация начнется после клика***

*Просьба смотреть в развернутом сниппете*

```css
.s0{fill:none;}
.container{
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  viewBox="0 0 900 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">



<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHI8O.png" width="100%" height="100%" /> 
    <!-- Трассы движения самолётов -->
 <path id="Moskwa" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" d="m262.2 360c0 0 52.8-99.6-44.3-116.7-58.7-10.4-109.7 52.1-109.7 52.1" class="s0"/>
  <path id="Vladivostok" d="m795.9 456.4c0 0-42.5-77.1-74.7-105.8-39.9-35.6-89-63.8-140.8-77-49.5-12.7-103.7-12.2-153.3 0-60.3 14.8-164.9 86.4-164.9 86.4" style="fill:none;stroke-width:2;stroke:#354ce7"/>
  <path id="Sankt-Peterburg" d="m262.2 360c0 0-10.3-83.1-38.9-108.9-27.4-24.7-107.4-26.5-107.4-26.5" style="fill:none;stroke-width:2;stroke:#5cd52d"/>
  <path id="Kaliningrad" d="m262.2 360c0 0-53.9-166.1-126-189.8C94.5 156.4 12.4 215.3 12.4 215.3" style="fill:none;stroke-width:2;stroke:#3761dc"/>
  <path id="Smolensk" d="m262.2 360c0 0-67.9-104.5-123-113.6-24.4-4-67.7 30.3-67.7 30.3" style="fill:none;stroke-width:2;stroke:#d52dce"/>
  <path id="Pyatigorsk" stroke="purple" stroke-width="2" d="m262.2 360c0 0-106.2-48.5-154.8-28.8-66.1 26.8-47.5 95.7-47.5 95.7" class="s0"/>
 
 <!-- Анимация полета самолетов вдоль маршрута  -->
  <text  fill="dodgerblue" y="3.5" x="-5" font-size="10px"  >  &#9992; 
    <animateMotion id="AnM" dur="8s" begin="svg1.click" fill="freeze" rotate="auto" restart="whenNotActive"   >
    <mpath xlink:href="#Moskwa"  />
    </animateMotion>
          <!-- Анимация увеличения, уменьшения размера самолёта -->
    <animateTransform  attributeName="transform" type="scale" keyTimes="0;0.2;0.8;1" values="1.5;4;4;2.5" dur="8s" begin="svg1.click" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
</text>   
   <text  fill="purple" y="3.5" x="-5" font-size="10px"  >  &#9992; 
    <animateMotion id="AnV" dur="16s" begin="svg1.click" fill="freeze" rotate="auto" restart="whenNotActive"  >
    <mpath xlink:href="#Vladivostok" />
    </animateMotion>
    <animateTransform  attributeName="transform" type="scale" keyTimes="0;0.2;0.8;1" values="3;6;6;3" dur="16s" begin="svg1.click"  fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
   </text> 
<text  fill="crimson" y="3.5" x="-5" font-size="10px"  >  &#9992; 
    <animateMotion id="AnS" dur="8s" begin="svg1.click+5.5s" fill="freeze" rotate="auto" restart="whenNotActive"   >
    <mpath xlink:href="#Kaliningrad" />
    </animateMotion>
    <animateTransform  attributeName="transform" type="scale" keyTimes="0;0.2;0.8;1" values="1.5;4;4;2.5" dur="8s" begin="svg1.click+5.5s"  fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
</text>       
    <text  fill="green" y="3.5" x="-5" font-size="10px"  >  &#9992; 
        <animateMotion id="AnS" dur="8s" begin="svg1.click+2s" fill="freeze" rotate="auto" restart="whenNotActive">
           <mpath xlink:href="#Sankt-Peterburg" />
        </animateMotion>
        <animateTransform  attributeName="transform" type="scale" keyTimes="0;0.2;0.8;1" values="1.5;4;4;2.5" dur="8s" begin="svg1.click+2s"  fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
    </text>      
<text  fill="brown" y="3.5" x="-5" font-size="10px"  >  &#9992; 
        <animateMotion id="AnS" dur="8s" begin="svg1.click+5s" fill="freeze" rotate="auto" restart="whenNotActive">
           <mpath xlink:href="#Smolensk" />
        </animateMotion>
        <animateTransform  attributeName="transform" type="scale" keyTimes="0;0.2;0.8;1" values="1.5;4;4;2.5" dur="8s" begin="svg1.click+5s"  fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
</text>  
      <text  fill="purple" y="3.5" x="-5" font-size="10px"  >  &#9992; 
        <animateMotion id="AnS" dur="8s" begin="svg1.click+8s" fill="freeze" rotate="auto" restart="whenNotActive">
           <mpath xlink:href="#Pyatigorsk" />
        </animateMotion>
        <animateTransform  attributeName="transform" type="scale" keyTimes="0;0.2;0.8;1" values="1.5;4;4;2.5" dur="8s" begin="svg1.click+8s"  fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
      </text>           
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за туториал, интересная реализация.